# Iterate compound returns in R (like Excel Product function)

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to write a simple function that reproduces the PRODUCT function in Excel that can be used to calculate returns on investments. Given a vector of returns over a period (as below), I'd like to calculate the total return over the entire holding period.

```
library(scales)
vec=c(2.1,3.1,5,-2.3,1.7,-9.8)
vecpercent=percent(vec/100)
```

In Excel this would be calculated as an array function like so: {=1+PRODUCT(B4:B9)-1}, if the returns in "vecpercent" were in cells B4 through B9.This is equivalent to (1+r1)*(1+r2)*...(1+rn), where n is the number of periods.

I am trying to solve this with a for loop, which I realize is taboo in the R world. I'd love to hear a better way, if possible. But if a loop is needed, do I also need to make a "helper" column where I multiply each rate of return with the previous one?

Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing taboo about for-loops in this situation. R doesn't support stochastic calculations very well and for-loops are fine as long as you pre-allocate and don't use wasteful operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the (vectorized) `cumprod` function:

```
cumprod(1 + vec / 100) - 1
# [1]  0.0210000  0.0526510  0.1052835  0.0798620  0.0982197 -0.0094058
```

If you are only looking for the last value, you can use `prod`:

```
prod(1 + vec / 100) - 1
[1] -0.0094058
```

(which you can feed into `percent()` again, for pretty formatting.)

Comment: No problem. Also, since you are familiar with Excel, I would recommend you look into using R data.frames. It's the perfect data structure for this type of column-wise work.